# X-UA-Compatible in DotNetNuke

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dotnetnuke, x-ua-compatible

Is there a way to implement a X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1 line of code in the .ascx of a DotNetNuke site? Or is there another place to implement it?

Presently, I've got:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

under the DNN declarations/server calls. Is this right?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Turns out, adding

```
<![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >]]>
```

to the doctype.xml file will work.

Comment: Adding the meta tag in the [skin_name].doctype.xml will work, but you will end up with a site that has invalid markup since the <meta> tag will be rendered between the DOCTYPE and the <html> tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [40Fingers Skin Helper](http://stylehelper.codeplex.com/) to add that `<meta>` tag to the head of the page.  After installing, you'd register it on the page like so:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="fortyfingers" TagName="STYLEHELPER" Src="~/DesktopModules/40Fingers/SkinObjects/StyleHelper/StyleHelper.ascx" %>
```

Then you can add it to your skin, like this:

```
<fortyfingers:STYLEHELPER AddToHead='<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">' runat="server" />
```

DNN also has its own `Meta` skin object, but currently it [only exposes `name` and `content`, not `http-equiv`](http://support.dotnetnuke.com/Default.aspx?p=2&i=18662) (similarly, if you need to add a name/content meta  tag, the Skin Helper provides an `AddMetaTags` property, too).

Comment: Thanks! I did some extra research in the meantime, putting `<![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >]]>` in the doctype.xml file, it works as well.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would.  Make sure you also include a doctype in there, too, before the `<meta>`.